# Timeout method still called in Vue although it is cleared

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to delay an API call to get search results, by using `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` methods in my Vue app.

I've created a watcher on a search variable, so every time it changes, the code should run (which in fact is happening).

```
  watch: {
    search: function (search) {
        var self = this;
        if (search.length >= 1) {
            if (this.time) {
                console.log(this.time)
                clearTimeout(this.time);
                console.log(this.time)
            }
            this.time = setTimeout( self.searchAccounts, 500);
        } else {
          this.restoreAccounts()
        }
    },
```

The idea is that if the method runs within the next 500ms, the previous API call is cancelled. Unfortunately even if I type 3 characters very fast ("ABC"), it still generates 3 API calls with `q=A` `q=AB` and `q=ABC`. So it seems my timer is not getting cleared. Any idea why this is not playing nicely?

Edit: Even after changing the `setTimeout` call to be a reference, the same issue still occurs, and the function is actually being called 3 times.

Comment: `self.searchAccounts()` your executing this function immediately, not when the timeout is triggered, try removing the brackets.  Or use an arrow function.. `()=>self.searchAccounts()`

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
this.time = setTimeout( self.searchAccounts(), 500);
```

is the culprit.

`setimeout()` expects a callback function as the first argument and you are assigning the return value of `searchAccounts()` instead.

Try

```
this.time = setTimeout( self.searchAccounts, 500);
```

Comment: I tried this as well, but still it seems to call the API 3 times when typing in 'ABC'